# Adding force to a unit based on a gameobject's rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to a add force to an enemy when my bullet hits it. I want the force to push the enemy away. I was having trouble finding a tutorial about this, so I'm assuming it's quite simple, and I'm oversimplifying it.

Note: this is for Unity2D

This is the code I have currently:

```
  if (collision.CompareTag("Bullet"))
    {
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        if (collision.transform.rotation = 180)
        {
            rb.AddForce(transform.right * knockback * -1, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
        else
        {
            rb.AddForce(transform.right * knockback * 1, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }

    }
```

However, Unity is responding to this code with:

> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'UnityEngine.Quaternion.'

What I'm getting from this error is that I need to convert an int to a Quaternion, but how do I do so?.

If there are ways to make this code neater, please let me know.

Apologies if this is a repeat question, but I did try to find others. More apologies if this is a formatting nightmare.

Comment: By the way, the assignment operator `=`  is not meant to be used to compare objects. Unit mismatch aside, you probably meant to use the equality operator `==`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that `collision.transform.rotation = 180` is the line it is erroring on.
In this case it doesn't make sense to compare an int to a Quaternion because they aren't the same units.

Because there are approaches far simpler than comparing a Quaternion in this use case, I'll leave out Quaternions in this answer in order to keep this response concise.

---

For figuring out which side the bullet hits on, it will be easier to compare to x positions of your enemy and bullet, like so:

```cs
if (collision.transform.position.x > transform.position.x)
{
    // Bullet is on right
}
else
{
    // Bullet is on left
}
```

Another way to approach this is to use the bullet's .right direction to apply the force.
Doing it this way will apply the force based on the direction the bullet is facing.

```cs
rb.AddForce(collision.transform.right * knockback, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

In both cases, the code decides on a direction to apply the knockback in, although in different ways.